# Android registerForActivityResult ActivityResultCallback not working when App was stopped on low memory

Tags: android, memory, android-activity

My app is running on devices with low memory so it happens from time to time that other activities are stopped.
The problem is that if I start another activity with registerForActivityResult, and the starting activity is stopped because of low memory, the callback won't be called and the complete App flow is broken.
Why does this function exist when it cannot handle this case?

Is there a solution or do i miss anything?

Comment: This is not the problem of the function `registerForActivityResult`, it's either the problem of a device that does not have enough memory to handle the load or the problem of your application that is not careful with the available memory resources. You can profile your app to check how much of the available resources it uses at any moment and find spots where the load could be reduced. [Here is how](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler). This, I think, is the best you can do.

Comment: The device we are dealing with is a Zebra device (1gb) which is running some other applications and services (including device management) so we cannot do much about it. Our app is not consuming much memory. I think it is a little bit old fashioned problem because todays devices have enough memory to close other activities according to the "out of memory score" - which won't be the starting activity -, but if there is only that little space left also the previous activity is stopped. And if you use registerForActivityResult you have a problem.